# How to sum up Datastructure subfields in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Today I read the `Who knew you could do that` manual. I came across the %XFoot BIF that calculates the sum of an (numeric) array. So I thought there must be a way to sum up the subfields of a datastructure array that holds (e.g.) invoices and their value.

To get the invoice Data I run embedded SQL that stores the data from the database in a qualified datastructure which is defined as dim(1000).

I tried to `%XFoot(invoiceDS:1:1000)` and `%XFoot(invoiceDS(*).value:1:1000)`. None of them compiled since the qualified expression is not allowd as parameter for %XFoot.

Then I tried to get a sub-Portion if the datastructure array with `%SubArr(invoiceDS(*).value:1:1000)`. But this also failed since 'value' is no fieldgroup.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a DS, %xfoot works only with array.

But, if you have some numeric consecutive fields (with same length and tipe) you can use a pointer

```
d $ptr_fields     s               *   inz(%addr(first_field))  
d ar_fields       s                   like(first_field) dim(number_of_fields)
d                                     based($ptr_fields)
```

and then you can do the %xfoot of ar_fileds

But in your case, with a DS DIM(1000)... you have to do a LOOP, because xfoot sum an array (so an data is "horizontally, dimensional DS are "vertically".

LOOP:

```
total = *Zero ;
For count = 1 To 1000 ;
 total += DsName(count).Field ;
EndFor ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I just have to run over the datastructure array with an Do loop, extract the invoice value, put them into a seperate array and use %XFoot on the value array

```
 H DECEDIT('0,') DATEDIT(*DMY.) dftactgrp(*no)
 H
 D invoiceDS       ds                  dim(10) qualified
 D   nbr                   1      6s 0 inz(*zeros)
 D   value                 7     14s 2 inz(*zeros)
 D
 D invoice_sum     s              8s 0 inz(*zeros)
 D values          s              8s 0 inz(*zeros) dim(10)
 D i               s              5i 0 inz(*zeros)
 D start           s              4s 0 inz(4711)
 D
 C
 C     1             do        10            i
 C                   eval      invoiceDS(i).nbr = start + i - 1
 C                   eval      invoiceDS(i).value = 100.00
 C                   enddo
 C
 C                   eval      i = 0
 C     1             do        10            i
 C                   eval      values(i) = invoiceDS(i).value
 C                   enddo
 C                   eval      invoice_sum = %xfoot(values)
 C     invoice_sum   dsply
 C
 C                   move      *on           *inlr
```

Comment: But why would you do this? If you are going to loop through the DS array anyway, why not just go ahead and accumulate your totals right there instead of allocating extra memory for an array, and moving everything to the array just so %xfoot can loop through the array again and accumulate the totals? I know %xfoot is kinda cool and unique, but it is also a bit limited these days.

Comment: ....I was so fixed to the idea of calculating the sum using %xfoot, I didn't even thought about that. Thanks!